# Maximum audio/video delay for peer to peer communication

Tags: audio, video, delay, webrtc

Is there any standard for tolerable delay in audio and video communication for web ? I have noticed delay using my WebRTC application and want to compare it with the standard (if any).

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latency_%28audio%29) has mentioned following delays:

- Live audio : several hundred ms to a few seconds,
- Telephone Calls : 200ms,
- IP calls: min 20ms, max 150ms
- Computer audio: 500ms

From book ["Deploying QoS for Cisco IP and Next Generation Networks: The Definitive Guide" By Vinod Joseph, Brett Chapman](https://books.google.com.bd/books?id=bMKFYMql8uoC&pg=PA109&lpg=PA109):

- Voice : 150ms one way
- Interactive video: 150ms (upto 200ms)
- live : 150ms
- video on demand : 150ms
- Multimedia conferencing and streaming: >400ms

Which one should i compare with ? Interactive video, Multimedia conferencing or IP calls ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is for instance several recommendations of the ITU (International Telecommunication Union):

- [Y.1541](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-Y.1541-201112-I/en): Network aspects (network delay, jitter, packet loss, etc.)
- [G.114](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-G.114-200305-I/en): Mouth-To-Ear delay ( < 200ms OK, > 400ms KO ) - audio only

Comment: Thank you Antonin. So far, the mouth-to-ear delay sounds promising for a reference.

Comment: Is there something similar to Mouth-To-Ear delay for video? Like Image-Capture-To-Image-Watched delay?